# Dart - find most common character in a string

Tags: dart

I'm stuck on this common interview question using Dart.  I need to return the most common character in a given string.  I'm trying to create a map with a count for each character as the first step.

This is my progress so far:

```
main(List<String> arguments) {
  maxChar('hello');
}

void maxChar(String word) {
  Map<String, int> charMap = {};
  int max = 0;
  String maxChar = '';
  word.split('').forEach((char) {
    if(charMap.containsValue(char)) {
      charMap[char]+1;
      return;
    } else {
      charMap[char] = 1;
    }
  });
  print(charMap);
}
```

Right now its not even counting the correct amount of the letter 'l'.  It's outputting:

```
{h: 1, e: 1, l: 1, o: 1}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there an easier way to return the most common character in a String in Dart?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Ok, I've solved it, but surely there is a more concise way of solving this problem.  See my solution below:

```
main(List<String> arguments) {
  print(max_char.maxChar('hello'));
}

String maxChar(String word) {
  Map<String, int> charMap = {};
  int max = -1;
  String maxChar = '';
  word.split('').forEach((char) {
    if(charMap.containsKey(char)) {
      charMap[char]++;
      return;
    } else {
      charMap[char] = 1;
    }
  });
  charMap.forEach((k,v) {
    if(v > max) {
      max = v;
      maxChar = k;
    }
  });
  return maxChar;
}
```

Comment: Your're computing charMap[char]+1, but you're not doing anything with the result (i.e. storing it in the map).

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Never used Dart, but I guess `charMap[char] = charMap[char] + 1;` or `charMap[char] += 1`

Comment: actually charMap[char]+1 works, the problem was i was using containsValue instead of containsKey

Comment: you could also use the null aware operator in the first forEach loop: `charMap[char] ??= 0;
     charMap[char]++;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shorter approach to counting the characters is definitely possible:

```
String charCount(String chars) {
  int maxChar = -1;
  int maxCount = 0;
  var counts = <int, int>{};
  for (var char in chars.runes) {
    int count = counts.update(char, (n) => n + 1, ifAbsent: () => 1);
    if (count > maxCount) {
      maxCount = count;
      maxChar = char;
    }
  }
  return String.fromCharCode(maxChar);
}
```

If you just want to count the characters, you can remove all the lines mentioning `maxCount` and `maxChar`.

I use integers to represent the characters instead of strings. That's cheaper and just as precise, and it allows you to recognize and combine Unicode UTF-16 surrogates.